# What does this import error mean? "Invalid value for field(s) : ... Country input value not in country table"

Tags: import, error

I am getting a crazy import error message:

> Invalid value for field(s) : Addressee must be one of the configured format options. Check Administer >> System Settings >> Option Groups >> Addressee for valid values; State/Province; Country input value not in country table: The Country value appears to be invalid. It does not match any value in CiviCRM table of countries.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like the issue is that **CiviCRM doesn't recognise the contents of your Country column** (for some rows).

In the import UI, you should see an option to **download rows with errors**, and that CSV will report which exact country values CiviCRM does not recognise.

Eg, CiviCRM would accept either `US` ([ISO-3166](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1)), `United States` (CiviCRM's label) or `1228` (CiviCRM's DB ID), but if the CSV contains `United States of America` or `U.S.A`, then CiviCRM might not recognise that alternative.

Cleaning this up is usually as simple as a *Find & Replace* in your import spreadsheet before re-importing. You might then rinse and repeat (`N.Z` => `NZ` or `New Zealand`) for further countries, or other invalid data that needs cleanup.

To get a working *import* format, try *exporting* a few contacts (even if you have to create a few first), then use the resulting CSV as basis for your next import.

Comment: Or if you have access to the db, have a look in civicrm_country for a full list of the ID, the 'name' and the ISO code (which I think is also accepted) i.e. US (chris if you agree maybe update your answer re ISO)